# Qual é a diferença entre % e %% em C?

Tags: c, sintaxe, formatação

Qual é a diferença entre usar o `%` e o `%%` na linguagem C?

Comment: Se alguma das respostas abaixo te ajudou, é o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 4):

O símbolo `%` é usado em funções de entrada e saída de dados como o `printf()` e `scanf()`. Quando usa esse símbolo indica que o que vem a seguir é algo especial que tem um significado de como o dado deve ser formatado.

Por exemplo `%d` indica o que o dado deve ser um valor inteiro, ou `%s` deve ser uma *string*. Sem o símbolo seria só uma letra a ser usada de forma normal sem um significado especial. È mais ou menos como o `\n` que significa que é para pular uma linha, sem a barra invertida seria só uma letra `n`.

Assim como `\\` significa que só quer uma barra invertida, o `%%` significa que só quer um símbolo de percentual. Porque pensa bem, se esse símbolo indica que ele é especial, quando você quer que ele deixe de ser especial o tem que ter uma forma diferente de usar, então o primeiro símbolo diz que há algo especial à seguir e o que vem depois dele é outro símbolo igual, então, especialmente, ele trata aquele símbolo como um caractere normal a ser usado no texto usado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) {
    printf("Strings:\n");
    const char* s = "Hello";
    printf("\t.%10s.\n\t.%-10s.\n\t.%*s.\n", s, s, 10, s);
    printf("Characters:\t%c %%\n", 65); //olha o duplo aqui, veja o resultado
    printf("Integers\n");
    printf("Decimal:\t%i %d %.6i %i %.0i %+i %i\n", 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, -4);
    printf("Hexadecimal:\t%x %x %X %#x\n", 5, 10, 10, 6);
    printf("Octal:\t%o %#o %#o\n", 10, 10, 4);
    printf("Floating point\n");
    printf("Rounding:\t%f %.0f %.32f\n", 1.5, 1.5, 1.3);
    printf("Padding:\t%05.2f %.2f %5.2f\n", 1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    printf("Scientific:\t%E %e\n", 1.5, 1.5);
    printf("Hexadecimal:\t%a %A\n", 1.5, 1.5);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5D8CsX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/esuhtwxa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/FormatDoublePercent.c).

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Existe algo parecido com o arroba do antes das strings em C# em C?

Comment: Não em C padrão.

Answer (score 4):

Caso esteja falando de printf ou scanf. Aqui uma tabela para melhor te ajudar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
printf ("Teste %% %%") // "Teste % %"
printf ("%f",40.345) // "40.345"
printf ("Um caractere %c e um inteiro %d",'D',120) // "Um caractere D e um inteiro
120"
printf ("%s e um exemplo","Este") // "Este e um exemplo"
printf ("%s%d%%","Juros de ",10) // "Juros de 10%"
```

Em outro ponto o % também pega o resto de uma divisão:

O operador % retorna o resto da divisão de um número por outro.

```
5 % 2 = 1
4 % 2 = 0
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado a todos 